# Camelia leaf turning brown

Tags: plant-health, containers, shrubs, camellia

[!I have planted my [image: camelia] in a barrel. Few months back its leaf started turn yellowish . I feed it with iron containing fertilizer . Now its leaf becoming brown , like it caught fire. What i have to do now?..
This plant is not over watered and it now getting better sun than it was on ground. 
This plant was perfect while it was on ground?.So the main question is camelia good to grow on barrel?.
[image]

[image]
enter image description here

[image]

Comment: Few points for clarification please  - how long was this plant in the ground before you moved it to the barrel? And what part of the world are you in?

Comment: The pant was on ground for more than one year. I live in Wicklow, Ireland.

Answer (score 3):

You say you moved this Camellia from the ground into a barrel earlier this year - that might mean some  root damage was caused, and that would show itself in the foliage. It's not possible to see how big (or not) the Camellia is from your photograph in relation to its container, nor do you say whether it flowered this year, both of which would have been useful to know. However, assuming there was no root damage, and that you did not cram the rootball into the barrel (in other words, there was plenty of room to accommodate the roots without cramping them up to get them in) the most likely explanation is you've not kept up with sufficient watering, given it's now in more direct sun than it was. This is a plant that prefers moist but well drained soil and partial shade; if you had a hot summer, the sun would have been very strong and may have scorched the leaves as well as causing a requirement for extra water - in such conditions, it should have been given a good gallon or so of water possibly twice a day, but certainly daily, reducing that to every few days once the heat abated.

You don't say if you used potting soil (hopefully you did, and it's not potted in soil from the garden), or what type - it should have been new, ericaceous potting compost, which is specially intended for use with acid loving plants such as Camellia. If you did not use this type of potting soil, it's probably worth unpotting it, removing what you can of the existing soil, and repotting using ericaceous. I'm  assuming there is good drainage from the barrel, either through the slats at the base if it has them, or it has drainage holes drilled into the bottom. It looks as though there are other plants in with the Camellia - remove those, it needs all the root space it can get.

Comment: I have added few more photos.. The one with flower was taken while I moved the plant. it was around march- may time. I used top soil with compost .

Comment: Ah, so summer bedding around it, and a half barrel rather than a barrel. I still think its worth repotting into ericaceous compost - you'll  be removing the summer bedding shortly anyway, so this month is a good time to do it. And don't add any plants to the half barrel next year ....at the size the Camellia is, it needs all that space for itself. You'll likely need a bigger pot in another year too...water in well after repotting, and keep well watered during hot weather.

Comment: Thanks for answering .. My last question ,I am now using iron solution when a gardener advised me when its leaf turn yellow .So that will make soil acidic right?.. Even if I use new  ericaceous compost ( as barrel is big I may have to spend lot) , will till gradually become non acidic after a while ?...As Camelia will flower only for a small period , I was bedding Gerunium to add a color. But planing that small plant affect the other one?..

Comment: Iron tonic only lasts a few months, it flushes out of the soil. If there's a lot of spare soil in the barrel, then its okay to add some temporary plants (pansies in winter, geraniums in summer, whatever) but after a year or so, if you find roots when you try to plant extra plants in there, or the Camellia has doubled its size,  don't put anything else in. Its probably as expensive to keep using iron tonic as it will be to replace the compost with ericaceous...

Comment: ? not understanding that...

Comment: I bought [ericaceous compost](https://www.bordnamonahorticulture.ie/home-gardening/gardening-products/soil-improvers/growise-premium-irish-moss-peat/) .Right now I am having geraniums , but now when i change the compost will that one good .Which small palnts you can suggest in this ne compost that will give some color.

Comment: If your link in the comment is what you bought, that isn't ericaceouis compost  - its sphagnum moss, which, whilst useful to add to soil, is not a growing medium on its own.  Link here to an example of ericaceous compost https://www.amazon.co.uk/WESTLAND-ERICACEOUS-COMPOST-GARDEN-CONTAINER/dp/B00J2ZG7JC - Levingtons also make one, usually available at most garden centres. Colour in winter is difficult with a restricted choice, so pansies or the little pot cyclamens the garden centres are full of now. Note the cyclamens will only flower up till christmas - pansies will go on to April/May.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering all my questions.. I bought this compost showing your ans and told the garden center that will help me to make my topsoil in barrel good for camellia .. my plan is to use this as a mix so that the topsoil will not go in waste .. otherwise I have to buy many bags to fill the whole barrel...

Comment: Okay, its your choice of course, but I will just say, one large bag (70 or 80 litre) of potting compost should easily have been sufficient to fill the half barrel...

Comment: You have answered all my doubts.. how can I ignore it... I have changed the compost and planted the pants you suggested.. now will hope for the best .. Pls check my last photo..thanks again

Comment: Well done! Looks good...just make sure to check if it  needs watering during the rest of October...